# Initializing IEnumerable<string> In C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have this object :

```
IEnumerable<string> m_oEnum = null;
```

and I'd like to initialize it. Tried with

```
IEnumerable<string> m_oEnum = new IEnumerable<string>() { "1", "2", "3"};
```

but it say "IEnumerable doesnt contain a method for add string. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Ok, adding to the answers stated you might be *also* looking for

```
IEnumerable<string> m_oEnum = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
```

or

```
IEnumerable<string> m_oEnum = new string[]{};
```

Comment: Old now, but I would avoid the second option. You might want this to interact with other IEnumerables that are not compatible with arrays.

Comment: Sometimes you'll need to cast this to an IEnumerable. Then a statement like this will do: `(IEnumerable<string>)new [] {"1", "2", "3"}`

Answer (score 123):

`IEnumerable<T>` is an interface. You need to initiate with a concrete type (that implements `IEnumerable<T>`). Example:

```
IEnumerable<string> m_oEnum = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3"};
```

Answer (score 39):

As `string[]` implements IEnumerable

```
IEnumerable<string> m_oEnum = new string[] {"1","2","3"}
```

Answer (score 23):

`IEnumerable` is just an interface and so can't be instantiated directly.

You need to create a concrete class (like a `List`)

```
IEnumerable<string> m_oEnum = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
```

you can then pass this to anything expecting an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 19):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetData()
{
    yield return "1";
    yield return "2";
    yield return "3";
}

IEnumerable<string> m_oEnum = GetData();
```

Comment: Although a little overkill, +1 for using yield

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro +1 for the rhyme

Answer (score 8):

IEnumerable is an interface, instead of looking for how to create an interface instance, create an implementation that matches the interface: create a list or an array.

```
IEnumerable<string> myStrings = new [] { "first item", "second item" };
IEnumerable<string> myStrings = new List<string> { "first item", "second item" };
```

Comment: The simplest: new[] {...}

Answer (score 7):

You cannot instantiate an interface - you must provide a concrete implementation of IEnumerable.

Comment: Feels more like a comment than an answer as stated.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a static method that will return desired IEnumerable like this :

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CreateEnumerable<T>(params T[] values) =>
    values;
//And then use it
IEnumerable<string> myStrings = CreateEnumerable("first item", "second item");//etc..
```

Alternatively just do :

```
IEnumerable<string> myStrings = new []{ "first item", "second item"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it by using the new `global using` in `c# 10`.

```cs
// this makes EnumerableHelpers static members accessible 
// from anywhere inside your project.
// you can keep this line in the same file as the helper class,
// or move it to your custom global using file.
global using static Utils.EnumerableHelpers;

namespace Utils;

public static class EnumerableHelpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns only non-null values from passed parameters as <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="values"></param>
    /// <returns><see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> of non-null values.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> NewEnumerable<T>(params T[] values)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Length == 0) yield break;

        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            // I added this condition for my use case, remove it if you want.
            if (item != null) yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is how to use it:

```cs
// Use Case 1
var numbers = NewEnumerable(1, 2, 3);

// Use Case 2
var strings = NewEnumerable<string>();
strings.Append("Hi!");
```